# Java - return type for enum values

Tags: java, generics, enums

Good day SO people. I have a problem regarding returning the inner enum values of my enum. I do not know which return type to use. I have tried googling and bumped into some solutions the uses generics however, I still have no luck. I do not know if my question has a solution or probably I did a bad design. So here goes, below
is my enum.

```
public enum KEYS
{
    A("value"),
    B("value"),
    C("value");

    public enum KEYS_GROUP_A
    {
        ITEM_A ("value"),
        ITEM_B ("value"),
        ITEM_C ("value");

        private String value;
        private KEYS_GROUP_A( String _value )
        {
            value = _value;
        }

        public String getVal()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public enum KEYS_GROUP_B
    {
        ITEM_A ("value"),
        ITEM_B ("value"),
        ITEM_C ("value");

        private String value;
        private KEYS_GROUP_B( String _value )
        {
            value = _value;
        }

        public String getVal()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public enum KEYS_GROUP_C
    {
        ITEM_A ("value"),
        ITEM_B ("value"),
        ITEM_C ("value");

        private String value;
        private KEYS_GROUP_C( String _value )
        {
            value = _value;
        }

        public String getVal()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private String value;
    private PROPERTY_KEYS(String _value)
    {
        value = _value;
    }

    public String getVal()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public <?> getEnumValues(int x)
    {
        if ( 0 == x )
        {
            return KEYS.KEYS_GROUP_A.values();
        }
        else if ( 1 == x )
        {
            return KEYS.KEYS_GROUP_B.values(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return KEYS.KEYS_GROUP_C.values();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is the `getEnumValues()` method. I have tried the return type `<T extends Enum<T>> T` but still an error occurs. Please tell if my design is bad or should not really be done. Please state some references. I'm willing to read and learn. Please shed some light! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "an error occurs" is not a description of an error. If you have a stack trace, post it. If you have a compile error, post the error.

Comment: Watch the constructor in KEYS_GROUP_B and KEYS_GROUP_C. A copy paste error where the constructors have been named KEYS_GROUP_A for all the 3 nested enumerations. PROPERTY_KEYS - what is that? Did you mean KEYS instead?

Comment: `( 0 == x )` won't compile, you are comparing `int` with `String`.

Comment: The most specific return type for `getEnumValues` would be `Enum<?>[]`.

Comment: sorry guys I now edited the question. Anyway my error is type mismatch: cannot convert KEYS.KEYS_GROUP_A[] to T[] sir @khelwood

Comment: What is T? Where is the compiler getting T from? Is this the actual code that you are getting an error with as this code won't even compile? Try changing the return value to the one Andy suggested and also make sure that you fix the compilation errors related to comparing String with an integer...let us know if you are still facing issues

Comment: I tried your solution sir @AndyTurner and it says "This method must a return a result of type Enum<?>[]

Comment: Try fixing the syntax errors earlier in the code, e.g. `private String value,`.

Comment: Oh wait my bad.. The suggestion of sir @AndyTurner worked!! :) Thank you guys and sorry for all the hassle. Sir Andy if you could post your answer pls. I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most specific type you can return is

```
public Enum<?>[] getEnumValues(int x)
```

You can return a more "useful" type if you define an interface like this:

```
interface HasVal { String getVal(); }
```

then make your enums all implement that interface, e.g.:

```
public enum KEYS_GROUP_A implements HasVal {
  // ...

  @Override public String getVal() { return value; }
}
```

Then you can return

```
public HasVal[] getEnumValues(int x)
```

and be able to invoke the `getVal` method on the instances:

```
for (HasVal val : getEnumValues(x)) {
  System.out.println(val.getVal());
}
```

---

You can't use:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T[] getEnumValues(int x)
```

because this isn't satisfiable for a general `T`. For instance, I could define:

```
enum Blah {}
```

and then try to invoke:

```
Blah[] blah = getEnumValues(1);
```

That wouldn't be type safe, because at least one (well, all, actually) of the code paths return a value which is not covariant with `Blah[]`.

Comment: Thank you sir. One question though how can I iterate through this return value? Oh wait I'll check it first in google. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: It's just an array. `for (Enum<?> value : getEnumValues(i)) { }`.

Comment: Thank you sir! You rock! :)